# Error (10453): VHDL error at <> right bound (0) of slice must belong to range (54 downto 5) of corresponding object

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am making an Avalon memory mapped component.

I wish to send the data of the registers directly to another VHDL entity. But doing this gives me the following error.

The error is when I try to add the coeff array to the instance.

```vhdl
fir_instance : fir_parralel 
        generic map(
            ...
        )
        port map(
            ... -- here \/
            coeff   => regs(N_OF_REGS - 1 downto COEFF_ADDRESS)(COEFF_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
        );
```

The regs is made as follows:

```vhdl
type fir_array is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector; --this is a 2d array pretty much
signal regs: fir_array(N_OF_REGS-1 downto 0)(31 downto 0) := (others =>(others => '0'));
```

The fir_parralel portmap looks as follows

```vhdl
entity fir_parralel is
    generic(
        TAPS            : natural range 8 to 64   := 50; -- amount of taps, maximum
        INPUT_WIDTH     : natural range 8 to 25   := 16; -- size of input and output format
        COEFF_WIDTH     : natural range 8 to 18   := 16; -- maximum size of coefficients of the filter.
        OUTPUT_WIDTH    : natural range 8 to 43   := 16
    );
    port(
        clk     : in std_logic;
        reset   : in std_logic;
        enable  : in std_logic;
        tapset  : in integer range 0 to TAPS := TAPS; -- if you lower the taps in your coeff
        input   : in std_logic_vector(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        output  : out std_logic_vector(OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
        coeff   : in fir_array(TAPS - 1 downto 0)(COEFF_WIDTH - 1 downto 0) -- the array of values we want to use for the gain functions
    );
end fir_parralel;
```

I made sure that `regs(N_OF_REGS - 1 downto COEFF_ADDRESS)` was the same size as the fir_parralel entity. Still I get these errors.

```
Error (10453): VHDL error at fir_parralel_avalon_interface.vhd(120): right bound (0) of slice must belong to range (54 downto 5) of corresponding object
```

```
Error (10346): VHDL error at fir_parralel_avalon_interface.vhd(106): formal port or parameter "coeff" must have actual or default value
```

tried fixing it, looked for this error code on stackoverflow, couldn't find that so I made this question so I and other future people can look this up on google.

Edit:

Fixed it with a generator.

```vhdl
coefficient_gen: for i in 0 to TAPS-1 generate
    coefficients(i) <= regs(i + COEFF_ADDRESS)(COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
end generate coefficient_gen;
```

Comment: See [ask], provide a [mcve] reproducing the error for the benefit of future readers and incidentally enabling [verifiable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8MzN.jpg) answers. An unbounded array definition in type fir_array requires -2008 which allows the use of non-static expressions as an actual in a port list utilizing an implicitly declared anonymous signal assigned the expression value. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clause.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot slice an array in more than on dimension at once. Slices can only take place in a single dimension at once. In your example, you are doing this by trying to slice 2 dimensions of `regs` when mapping it to `coeff`.

It might be a good idea to provide a conversion function of some kind where you declare `fir_array` to allow for this.

Comment: I tried ```for i in 0 to TAPS-1 loop  coefficients(i) <= regs(COEFF_ADDRESS+i)(COEFF_WIDTH - 1 downto 0); end loop;```
But it says illegal concurrent statement

Comment: Loops can only be used in concurrent regions - eg.  inside a process, function or procedure. Perhaps you want to use a `for..generate` ?

Comment: @cyborgdennett: Since this `for`/`generate` is driving `coefficients` not `regs`, that's a separate error caused by other code.